# .setValues errors due to undefined .length

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, typeerror

I am using a connected Gform to build a reordering list of parts. I have 4 different lists that are created through app script and are triggered by form submission, the problem is the function can not `.setValues` if the `.length` is `undefined`. As not all lists need to be updated at once. I am needing a workaround to allow the function to complete.

Getting Error "TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined." when any of the 4 lists has no additions to consider.

```
    rs.getRange(2,2,dsmSO.length,dsmSO[0].length).setValues(dsmSO);
  rs.getRange("B2:C").sort(3);
rs.getRange(2,6,dsmReorder.length,dsmReorder[0].length).setValues(dsmReorder);
  rs.getRange("F2:H").sort(7);
rs.getRange(2,10,oSO.length,oSO[0].length).setValues(oSO);
  rs.getRange("J2:J").sort(10);
rs.getRange(2,12,oReorder.length,oReorder[0].length).setValues(oReorder);
  rs.getRange("L2:O").sort(12);
```

Complete Code follows

```
    function finalCode(){
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      var control = ss.getSheetByName("Control");
      var sold = ss.getSheetByName("Sold");
      // Speacial Order Parts Range
      var newPart = control.getRange(2,2,control.getLastRow() -1,9).getValues();
      // Sold Parts Range
      var soldPart = sold.getRange(2,3,sold.getLastRow() - 1,4).getValues();
      // Results Sheet
      var rs = ss.getSheetByName("Results")

      var dsmReorder = [];
      var dsmSO = [];
      var oReorder = [];
      var oSO = [];

      // DsM Sold Loop
      for(var i = 2; i<soldPart.length;i++){
        if(soldPart[i][3] == ''){
          if(soldPart[i][0] != 'Kurt'){
            dsmReorder.push([soldPart[i][0],soldPart[i][1],soldPart[i][2]])}
          else if(soldPart[i][0] == 'Kurt'){
            oReorder.push([soldPart[i][1],soldPart[i][2]])}
          var d = new Date();
          sold.getRange(i + 2,6).setValue(d);
        }
      }

      for(var l = 2; l<newPart.length;l++){
        if(newPart[l][7] == ''){
          if(newPart[l][1] == 'New Item/Special Order'){
            if(newPart[l][0] != 'kurt@metrolockdm.com'){
              dsmSO.push([newPart[l][0],newPart[l][6]])}
            else if(newPart[l][0] == 'kurt@metrolockdm.com'){
              oSO.push([newPart[l][6]])}
            var d = new Date();
            control.getRange(l + 2,9).setValue(d)
          }
        }
      }
      rs.getRange(2,2,dsmSO.length,dsmSO[0].length).setValues(dsmSO);
      rs.getRange("B2:C").sort(3);
rs.getRange(2,6,dsmReorder.length,dsmReorder[0].length).setValues(dsmReorder);
      rs.getRange("F2:H").sort(7);
     rs.getRange(2,10,oSO.length,oSO[0].length).setValues(oSO);
      rs.getRange("J2:J").sort(10);
     rs.getRange(2,12,oReorder.length,oReorder[0].length).setValues(oReorder);
      rs.getRange("L2:O").sort(12);

    }
```

Comment: The problem isn't that the .length is undefined.  The problem is that  the object with that property is undefined.  What line is it on?  Please provide [mcve] and execution transcript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
if(dsmSO) {
  rs.getRange(2,2,dsmSO.length,dsmSO[0].length).setValues(dsmSO);
  ....
}
```